# CSS 'word-spacing' property not working properly

Tags: html, css, footer, word-spacing

I have an unordered list with list items that I want to spread evenly from each other but the elements don't spread evenly.

```
<footer>
    <ul class="footer">
        <li><a href="about">Name©2023</a></li>
        <li><a href="legal">Privacy&Legal</a></li>
        <li><a href="vin-recall-search">Vehicle Recalls</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="updates">Get Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="findus/list">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

In the CSS file:

```
footer li{
    word-spacing:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

The word spacing between the items isn't identical.
it looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you use the spacing on the li elements instead of the ul element.

You need to change your CSS like below.

```css
footer li{
    display:inline-block;
    word-spacing: normal;
}

footer ul{
    word-spacing:20px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="footer">
        <li><a href="about">Name©2023</a></li>
        <li><a href="legal">Privacy&Legal</a></li>
        <li><a href="vin-recall-search">Vehicle Recalls</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="updates">Get Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="findus/list">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new Flexbox specification as well

```css
footer ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default */
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
footer li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="footer">
        <li><a href="about">Name©2023</a></li>
        <li><a href="legal">Privacy&Legal</a></li>
        <li><a href="vin-recall-search">Vehicle Recalls</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="updates">Get Updates</a></li>
        <li><a href="findus/list">Locations</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

For Ref: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/